# return render is not working in another python file - Djanjo

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms

I'm working on registration page and for basic validation like if user already registered, password is complex or not etc .. for that I've created a separate file and and if all checks completed I am trying to redirect but from the secondary python file redirect and even render is not working it just simply return me the same registration page but when I use redirect on the same views.py file redirect is working. That is a weird behavior? Or I am doing something wrong?

**[views.py]**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from .utils.registration import Register
 
# Create your views here.
 
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST['name']
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
 
        # return redirect("/verification/")
 
        Register(request=request, name=name, username=username, email=email, password=password)


def verify_account(request):
    return render(request, "authorize/verify-account.html")
```

**[registration.py]**

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
 
 
class Register:
    def __init__(self, request, name, username, email, password) :
        self.request = request
        self.name = name
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.error_message = None
        self.is_email = User.objects.filter(email=self.email)
        self.is_username = User.objects.filter(username=self.username)
        
        self.is_user()
 
    def is_user(self):
        if self.is_email and self.is_username:
            print(1, "######################################################")
            self.error_message = "Hmm.. Seems like your email and username already registered with us."
            self.show_error()
 
        elif self.is_email:
            print(2, "######################################################")
            self.error_message = "Grr... This email is already registered with us"
            self.show_error()
 
        elif self.is_username:
            print(3, "######################################################")
            self.error_message = "Grr... This username is already registered with us"
            self.show_error()
 
        else: # email and username is not in DB so register the new user
            print(4, "######################################################")
            # user = User
            # return render(self.request, "authorize/verify-account.html")
            return redirect("/verification/")
 
 
    def show_error(self):
        messages.error(self.request, self.error_message)
        return render(self.request, "authorize/register.html")
```

---

*showing my urls.py and registration.html page as optional*

**[urls.py]**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'authorize'

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.register, name="register"),
    path('verification/', views.verify_account, name="verify-account"),
    path('login/', views.login, name="login"),
    path('rest-password/', views.reset_password, name="reset_password"),
]
```

**[register.html]**

```
{% extends 'authorize/navbar.html' %}

{% block title %}Register{% endblock %}
{% block active-register %}active{% endblock %}
{% block section %}

{% load static %}


    <section id="content" class="register-user">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="container-box">

                <div class="form-box">
                    <a href="/register.html"><div class="logo form-logo" style="background-image: url('{% static "authorize/images/booive-neon.svg" %}');"></div></a>
                    <h3>Register in to Booive</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="register-user-error">
                    {% for message in messages %}
                    <p>{{message}}</p>
                    {%endfor%}
                </div>
    
                <form action="" class="form-main" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-item">
                        <label for="">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="demo" id="name" required>

                        <div class="error-box">
                            <p id="name-err" style="text-align: start;"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-item">
                        <label for="">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="demo123" id="username" required>

                        <div class="error-box">
                            <p id="username-err" style="text-align: start;"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-item">
                        <label for="">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="demo@mail.com" id="email" required>

                        <div class="error-box">
                            <p id="email-err" style="text-align: start;"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="form-item">
                        <label for="">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="************" id="password" autocomplete="on" required>

                        <div class="error-box">
                            <p id="password-err" style="text-align: start;"></p>

                            <div class="error-box">
                                <p id="confirm-password-err" style="text-align: start;"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-item">
                        <label for="">Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="confirm-password" placeholder="************" id="confirm-password" autocomplete="on" required>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="form-item">
                        <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Register">
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="form-item text-center">
                        <div class="links">Already have an account? <a href="{% url 'authorize:login' %}">Login Now</a></div>
                    </div>
        
                    
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Where is /verification/ url connected?

Comment: show that file as well

Comment: @ElvinJafarov I've updated more information -

Answer (score 0):

you do not return the redirect/render function.

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST['name']
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
 
        # return redirect("/verification/")
 
        register = Register(request=request, name=name, username=username, email=email, password=password)
        return register.is_user()

class Register:
    def __init__(self, request, name, username, email, password) :
        self.request = request
        self.name = name
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.error_message = None
        self.is_email = User.objects.filter(email=self.email)
        self.is_username = User.objects.filter(username=self.username)

    def is_user(self):
        if self.is_email and self.is_username:
            print(1, "#####################")
            self.error_message = "Hmm.. Seems like your email and username already registered with us."
            return self.show_error()
 
        elif self.is_email:
            print(2, "##########################")
            self.error_message = "Grr... This email is already registered with us"
            return self.show_error()
 
        elif self.is_username:
            print(3, "########################")
            self.error_message = "Grr... This username is already registered with us"
            return self.show_error()
 
        else: # email and username is not in DB so register the new user
            print(4, "###########################")
            # user = User
            # return render(self.request, "authorize/verify-account.html")
            return redirect("/verification/")

    def show_error(self):
        messages.error(self.request, self.error_message)
        return render(self.request, "authorize/register.html")
```

But i think you can use Form for you POST data validation, probably better and more cleaner than you did
https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/topics/forms/

Comment: The reason why I am not using django forms is because, I want to get a hands-on experience of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript while learning Django, later on I want to start django-rest-framework with ReactJs- so in short I just want to create foundation and a good understanding of Front-end also

Comment: could you please explain why did you return `register.is_user()` in [views.py] when I am already returning inside Register class from [registration.py]

Comment: Because, redirect and render returns somethings. They will return a HttpResponse. it is this object which make the rendering. So you have to return the render/redirect what your is_user() returns.